# Lost Array After Validation Error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm working on a CakePHP project and I have User, Post and Location models among others.
User hasMany Location and Post belongsTo User so Location is not directly related to Post.

This is my code in the Post controller:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
       $this->loadModel('Location');
       $this->set('locations', $this->Location->find('all', array('conditions' => array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')))));
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is my code in the posts/add view:

```
<?php
$i = 0; $j = 0;
foreach ($locations as $location):
    $location_names[$i] = $location['Location']['name'];
    $i++;
endforeach;
echo "<select name=\"location\" onchange=\"select(this.value)\">";
echo "<option value=\"\">Select a saved location</option>";
foreach ($locations as $location):
    echo "<option value=\"" . $location['Location']['latitude'] . "," . $location['Location']['longitude'] . "\">" . $location_names[$j] . "</option>";
    $j++;
endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

If I enter a wrong value in one of the post inputs that has a validation rule in Post model, it redirects to the current add view, shows what is the validation error, but then the $locations array passed from controller to view disappears and can't use it in view and I get this error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: locations [APP\View\Posts\add.ctp, line 68]
```

Comment: Why do you have the condition of `if ($this->request->is('get'))` ?

Comment: Right, I deleted it and it worked, thanks :)

Comment: I added an answer to mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by where you set the `$locations` variable with `$this->set()`, and this is only happening in case of a GET request.

When submitting the form, you are sending a POST/PUT request instead of a GET and the code inside `if` clause is never executed - therefore `$locations` variable is available in your View file.

If you only want to load those values when displaying a clean form, you might change the `if` condition to check if `$this->request->data` array is populated with user's submitted values.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept it as an answer by clicking the arrow under this post, on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the condition of `if ($this->request->is('get'))` ?

If you don't use for any special purpose, then delete it and the variable `locations` will always be set.